# Why make a new instance?

Tags: c#

I would like to know why we need a new instance of a class?

```
int coin;

Random randomNum = new Random();
coin = randomNum.Next(0, 2);
```

I have to do this... `Random randomNum = new Random();`
To get this.. `randomNum.Next(0, 2)`

Why can't I just do...

`coin = random.Next(0, 2);`

why do I have to give it a variable "randomnum" first?

Comment: Why ask a question instead of reading the C# programming reference in the MSDN? Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx

Comment: Because it is an object and objects need to be created.  ESPECIALLY with `Random` where there are some things that take place to initialize internal seeds and values etc

Comment: Why? Because whomever designed the `Random` class in the base class library decides to make this an instance class instead of a static one. This code be for various reasons, such as allowing you to pass in a seed which helps generate the random value.

Comment: I see two questions here: 1) Why are there class instances? and 2) Why is `Next()` an instance method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say in real life you need a random number. You need to make a machine that can output a random number. So you get some blueprints on how to make such a machine, then you go away and make it. You can then sit down with the machine and use it to get your random numbers.

In the programming example `Random` is the blueprint to create such a machine, `randomNum` is the machine you made and `coin = randomNum.Next(0, 2);` is you using the machine to get your random numbers.

Comment: Very well explained. I understand very well now. Thank you

Comment: No problem! If you feel this answered your question, you should [accept it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to aid anyone searching a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You could write it this way if you do not want 2 assignments:

```
var coin = (new Random()).Next(0, 2);
```

However - this will still create a `new` instance of random. The reason why you have to create a new instance is because the class/method is not `static`.

Comment: This is an correct answer. In addition, there is good habbit to create variable Random static if you are going to use it multiple times.

Comment: @Malin: why create it static? Why not just use it in local scope or class scope as needed?

Comment: @siride because Random uses timestamp as seed thus numbers generated by Next() might not be random

Comment: @Malin, I mean why does it need to be static? You may have a place or set of places in code that need a sequence of random numbers, and that part of code can share an instance, but it doesn't need to be done with statics necessarily.

Comment: @sride I am not saying that it need to be, just that this is a good habbit.
And best practice (from my experience) is using static helper class for Random because of threading random problems.
And also : [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Object oriented programming uses the metaphor of objects that can model real-world concepts. A class is like a set of blueprints for an object. By creating a new *instance* of a class, you are using those blueprints in order to create the object. Once the object is created, you can then call methods on it (such as `Next(0, 2)` in your example).